# How to calculate sum of all elements of a list excluding few numbers?

Tags: python

Write a python program to calculate sum of all elements in a list  excluding the numbers between 5 and 8.
Take the list as l1=[1,5,3,6,8,9,19,17,14]

Comment: `num_sum = sum(x for x in l1 if x not in [5,8])`

Comment: Can you show what you've tried please? Assuming you cannot use `sum`, this problem still has quite a simple solution. If you're having trouble visualizing a solution, sit down with a pen and paper, and think about how you would do this manually. Once you've done this, figure out how to translate the process to Python code.

Comment: Your solution is a bit off @JosephM. He wants to exclude any numbers in the _range_ between `5` and `8`: _"[...] excluding the numbers **between** 5 and 8"_.

Comment: Did not notice that nor the no use of sum edit.


     `functools.reduce(lambda a,b : a + b if a not in range(5,9) else b,l1)`

Answer (score 2):

```
sum(x for x in l1 if x not in range(5,9))
```

Comment: Although the optimal way to solve the OP problem, it still uses the `sum` function, which he wishes to avoid.